# journalctl output format without timestamp but with specific output-fields

Tags: logging, embedded-linux, systemd-journald

I use journalctl and want to use an output format with which I can specify the output fields to be shown. These are for example verbose or json.

But as soon as I set these output formats, a giant UTC timestamp is automatically also added which confuses a lot and leads to very long outputs.

Can I specify the output fields to be displayed while I shut-down the timestamp?

I found this: [journalctl remove fields starting with underscore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66195097/journalctl-remove-fields-starting-with-underscore) but there is no answer to that question.
Thanking you in advance

Comment: I would be happy if someone can tell me if 
a) there is no solution to my question (journald cannot be configured like that)
b) my question is misplaced or somehow stupid
c) my question could not be understood

Thanks a lot

Comment: You can select only one field for `-o cat` bit for others you anyway will get ayt least few underscore fields  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/418349/print-only-timestamp-and-message-in-journalctl

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's too late to answer but,
you can print the formatted output using awk
something like this :

`journalctl -u apache2 | awk '{ for (i = 6; i <= NF; i++) printf "%s ",$i;print "" }'`

that transform

```
Jul 12 23:20:01 vmi1118987 systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Jul 12 23:20:02 vmi1118987 systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP Server.
Jul 12 23:40:01 vmi1118987 systemd[1]: Stopping The Apache HTTP Server...
```

into the

```
Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Started The Apache HTTP Server.
Stopping The Apache HTTP Server...
```